How to output transfer id for filepond?
I'm trying to output a 'transfer id' for filepond to recognize the file for chunked uploads.
Docs says:
FilePond will send a POST request (without file) to start a chunked transfer, expecting to receive a unique transfer id in the response body, it'll add the Upload-Length header to this request.
I output transferid that created in storage normally. As filepond requested to.
// Handle Filepond Inital request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && empty($_FILES)) {

    // Extract headers
    $uploadLength = $_SERVER['HTTP_UPLOAD_LENGTH'];
    $uploadName = $_SERVER['HTTP_UPLOAD_NAME'];

    // Create a unique directory for this upload session
    $uniqueId = uniqid();
    $tmpDir = UPLOAD_DIR . $uniqueId . '/';

    if (!file_exists($tmpDir)) {
        mkdir($tmpDir, 0777, true);
    }

    // Return the unique location id as plain text response
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    echo $uniqueId;
    exit();

}

Filepond still sends transferid as 'undefined' so i am not able to understand which transfer is it.

My filepond setup:
 FilePond.setOptions({
        maxFileSize: '1024MB',
        allowRevert: false,
        allowRemove: true,
        allowRetry: false,
        chunkUploads: true,
        chunkSize: '1MB',
        chunkRetryDelays: [500, 1000, 3000],
        server: {
            url: 'https://remote-storage-api.com/uploadv2.php',
            process: {
                method: 'POST',
                withCredentials: false,
                headers: {
                    //"token": achtung,
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + achtung,
                    "X-CHUNKED": true,
                },
                onload: (response) => {
                    
                    addProcessItem(data);
                },
                onerror: (response) => {
                    
                },
            },
        },
        instantUpload: false,
        allowMultiple: true,
        allowReplace: false,
    });

